# Is there detailed documentation on Facebook Application Development?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I recently began doing facebook application development.  But it seems that the information out there is somewhat spotty.  I've dug around in the facebook documentation and done many google searches to try to learn more.  But the question that always comes up in my mind is where are others learning this stuff?  I see a lot of examples (most recently FB.Data.query in the JS SDK) that contain details that I haven't found outlines for anywhere.  For example where does one learn what queries are allowed... To be able to query their database you would have to know the tables and structure which I haven't seen outlined anywhere.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook's API is a rapidly changing and poorly documented target. You'll find this happens frequently.

Regarding the queries, these use FQL - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: I could have sworn that page wasn't there before!  ;)  Thanks!